# Sum Embedded Document Fields in Mongo Aggregate Query

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregation-framework

Data looks like:

```
{
    "_id":5345345345,
    "city": "Detroit",
    "people":[
        {
            "name":"Larry",
            "value":1200
        },
        {
            "name":"Steve",
            "value":1100
        },
        {
            "name":"Larry",
            "value":1000
        },
        {
            "name":"Joe",
            "value":800
        },
        {
            "name":"Larry",
            "value":500
        },
        {
            "name":"Joe",
            "value":700
        }

    ]
}
```

I have this in the middle of an aggregate query.  What can I do from here to sum the value field and have unique entry for each person in "people"? i.e.

```
{
    "_id":5345345345,
    "city": "Detroit",
    "people":[
        {
            "name":"Larry",
            "value":2700
        },
        {
            "name":"Steve",
            "value":1100
        },
        {
            "name":"Joe",
            "value":1500
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, cannot have query that returns empty document in case the "people" array is empty, e.g., cannot do:

```
{$unwind:{
    path:people
    }
},
{$group :
    {
        _id:"$people.name",
        total_value:{"$sum":"people.value"}
    }
}
```

which would work fine, if it didn't return an empty document when people array is empty.

Need to use $addToSet and $sum somehow? How to do this keeping value associated with name?

Comment: you rolled my mind.

Comment: @Jack : Why can't you return an empty document when the _people_ array is empty? The query you have got there looks right (it's exactly what I'd recommend myself), so maybe your application's code needs to be able to deal with the empty-document case?

Comment: @VinceBowdren thanks for the input will probably end up doing that

Comment: @Jack Not sure if this is what you need. You can use `$match` stage to filter empty people array documents before you do `$unwind`. Something like `{$match:{"people":{$ne:[]}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$people",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true // this line!
        }
 }
```